# VBA - calculate and print answer for many rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am still new to vba and am writing a macro to calculate the time between two dates in two columns using dateDiff then print the difference in the cell next to it. i would also like do use a do until empty

Column A holds the start date
Column B holds the end date 
Column C will hold the answer

i have some useful code but most of it is written to understand the goal of the macro and needs changed.

```
Range("A2").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
 For i = 2 To 25
  date1 = ["A" & i]
  date2 = ["B" & i]
  answer = DateDiff("n", date1, date2)
  "C" & i = answer
 next i
Loop
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

a. You can't have a variable when using the shorthand `[]`:

```
[A1]
```

will work but

```
i = 1
["A" & i]
```

Will not.  So you must use.

```
Range("A" & i)
```

Or

```
Cells(i,1)
```

b. Your do loop does not change the ActiveCell. So it will never end if there is a value in A2

c. It is better practice to find the last row and use a FOR Loop. See here for many ways on finding the last row: [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

d. Get in the habit now of declaring the parent of **EVERY** Range object, even if it is the ActiveSheet.

e. Always declare every variable, even if you declare it as Variant.

```
Dim i as Long
Dim lastRow as long
Dim date1 as double
Dim Date2 as double
Dim answer as long
With ActiveSheet
 lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).row
 For i = 2 To lastRow
  date1 = .Cells(i,1)
  date2 = .Cells(i,2)
  answer = DateDiff("n", date1, date2)
  .Cells(i,3) = answer
 next i
End With
```

Comment: This is very helpful. when i use F8 to cycle through the for loop the answer variable is getting the correct answer but its not printing it into the corresponding row in column C.
    .Cells(i,3) = answer

is this line suppossed to do that?

Comment: I forgot the `End With`.  Try the edited code.  it works for me as is, make sure you do not have a typo on the output variables. @Peel

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I am also adding an if statement. there is a column "summary" and each cell either has yes or no. if the cell says no then i want this for loop to run and print in C.

'summary = .Cells (i, 4)' doesnt work do i add.value?

Comment: @Peel new question = new post.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of the format for dating, and assuming contiguous data, I would recommend the following:

```
Dim LR as Long
LR=Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("NAME").Range("C1:C"&LR).Formula="=B1-A1"
```

Hopefully that helps!

---

Edited per Scott's comment.

Comment: No need for the fill down: `Sheets("NAME").Range("C1:C"&LR).Formula="=B1-A1"` is sufficient for both lines.  Excel will change the reference as needed.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for that; I know I've had issues in the past, but I can't remember specifics and will trust you because... you're you.  Lol, you've not steered me wrong to date!